# SwiftUI - Remove space between 2 lists (iOS 16)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am working on a complex app using SwiftUI, but I created a small sample working app to explain my problem. I have a sheet/panel which has 2 separate lists and I am unable to figure out what is causing to have so much of space between 2 lists.

**PanelB** in my code below is what I am talking about which has lists *'DateTimeView'* and *'ResultsDisplayList'*.

PanelA might be unnecessary code but I just added it to show the flow of my app incase any of PanelA logic is causing it. Any idea what is the cause of extra space between 2 lists?

***Image:***

[image]

***Code:***

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showPanel: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
       NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello World - Click Me").font(.largeTitle).foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.showPanel = true
                    }
            }.sheet(isPresented: $showPanel) {
                ZStack {
                    Color.secondary
                    PanelA().padding(.top, 15.0)
                }
            }
       }
    }
}
    
struct PanelA: View {
    @State var showPanel: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Button {
                    showPanel = true
                } label: {
                    Text("Click Me")
                }
                .buttonBorderShape(.roundedRectangle(radius: 15.0))
                .padding()
                .background(Color.teal)
            }
            .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
            .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled)
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showPanel) {
                PanelB()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PanelB: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
           Color.purple.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                DateTimeView().padding(.bottom, 20.0)
                ResultsDisplayList()
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color.purple)
        }
    }
}

struct DateTimeView: View {
    @State private var startDateTime = Date.now
    @State private var isAllDay = true

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section("Event Date".uppercased()) {
                Toggle("all day", isOn: $isAllDay)
                DatePicker(selection: $startDateTime, in: startDateTime..., displayedComponents: [.date]) {
                    Text("select date time").font(.body).foregroundColor(Color.black)
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
    }
}

struct ResultsDisplayList: View {
    let results = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pineapple", "Cherries", "Strawberries", "Banana"]
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { _ in
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8.0) {
                List {
                    Section {
                        ForEach(results, id: \.hashValue) { result in
                            Text(result).font(.body)
                        }
                    } header: {
                        Text("Results List")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
            UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely due to the fact you’re using two Lists (which take all available space when adding to a view, as well as VStack and ScrollView).

It seems the `ScrollViewReader` and the `VStack` you added into the results have no use. Try using a single instance of list to wrap all your sections.

If the layout you expect requires these wrappers (which are not supported by List as children), you might want to extract the  `DateTimeView` and re-create the ui using something other than List.

Comment: That's interesting. My event date view is reusable and hence I created it as a separate list. I don't really need ScrollViewReader and VStack, but removing them didn't make a difference so I will have to merge both DatetimeView and SearchResults into one list.